# Android - Pause Activity and wait for user input

Tags: java, android, android-activity

My MainActivity starts with loading an Email address from SharedPreferences.
If there is none, then a popup window appears and asks for your Email.
This is on first ever startup only.

But the onCreate does not wait for that popup to dismiss and continues in background.
The Email is needed just after that at several positions.
My current solution is a manual app restart.

How can you pause the onCreate and wait until the email address is typed in and the submit button is pressed. Can you check if it is dismissed or something?

**A lot of things are cut away in those code segments**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        loadEmailAddress();
        if (email.equals("")) {
            setEmailAddress();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
```

```
    private void setEmailAddress() {
        final AlertDialog dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

        Button submit = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.submit);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final TextInputLayout layoutEditEmail = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.layout_edit_email);
                String editEmail = Objects.requireNonNull(layoutEditEmail.getEditText()).getText().toString();

                saveEmailAddress(editEmail);
                dialogBuilder.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: One approach is to start a new activity to prompt for needed information and `finish` the activity on valid entry and returning to the original activity.

Comment: where dialogBuilder.show() ?